# Krpoki Sudoko Translation in CNF

Tags: discussion

I am trying to solve Kropki Sudoko using CNF formulas.
Here are the formulas that I have created till now

1. - For each pre-assigned entry on the board in the initial board, a unit clause is defined as:

     $S_{xyz}$
   - There is at least one number in each entry :-
     $$
      \bigwedge_{x=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{y=1}^{9} \bigvee_{z=1}^{9} S_{xyz}
      $$

- Each number appears only once in a given row :-
  $$
    \bigwedge_{z=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{x=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{y=1}^{8} \bigwedge_{i=y+1}^{9} (\neg S_{xyz} \vee \neg S_{xiz})
    $$
- Each number appears only once in a given column:-
  $$
    \bigwedge_{z=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{y=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{x=1}^{8} \bigwedge_{i=x+1}^{9} (\neg S_{xyz} \vee \neg S_{iyz})
    $$
- Each number appears only once in each sub-grid :-
  $$
    \bigwedge_{z=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{i=0}^{2} \bigwedge_{j=0}^{2} \bigwedge_{x=1}^{2} \bigwedge_{y=1}^{3} \bigwedge_{k=x+1}^{9} \bigwedge_{l=1,y\neq l}^{9} (\neg S_{(3i+x)(3j+y)z} \vee \neg S_{(3i+k)(3j+l)z})
    $$

Now I am having trouble representing black dots (which means adjacent squares should be double of each other) and white dots (which means adjacent squares should be consecutive) in **CNF formulas** like above

Comment: MathJax help: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/372/51  or Unicode: 

• \&bull; ◦ \&#x25E6;